# How to dynamically change exportable Datatable button names after instantiation?

Tags: button, datatable, export, action, config

How to dynamically change exportable Datatable button names after they have already instantiated?  Or how do I get my fnDeleteRow method to "activate" dynamically so that the existing buttons dynamically rename themselves?   If they don't refresh themselves, I would like for the Do Stuff button to change the names of the other two (Excel and PDF) button names.  (Isn't fnDeleteRow supposed to update ALL parts of the datatable?  Are the button names cached?)
Here's part of the datatabe:

```
 ,"dom": 'B<"ui-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr ui-helper-clearfix">'
    ,"columnDefs": [   
                        {
                            "targets": [ 0, 1, 2, 3],
                            "visible": false,
                            "searchable": false
                        }
                      ] 
        , buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        name:  'excelBtn',
                        text: function ( dt, button, config ) {
                                 return 'Export all ' + dt.data().count() + ' entries to Excel' 
                        }       
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5', 
                        orientation: 'landscape',
                        name:  'pdfBtn',
                        action: function(e, dt, button, config) {
                            config.text = 'Export all ' + dt.data().count() + ' entries to PDF';
                            $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.pdfHtml5.action(e, dt, button, config);
                          }
                        ,header: true
                        ,title: 'System'
                        ,fontSize: '15'
                        ,exportOptions: {
                                columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3]
                        }
                        ,customize: function ( doc ) {
                            doc["footer"] = function(currentPage, pageCount) {
                              return { text: ' Page ' + currentPage.toString() + ' of ' + pageCount + ' \r \n ' + getCurrentDateTime() , alignment: 'center' };
                            };

                            doc.content.splice( 1, 0, {
                                margin: [ 0, 0, 0, 12 ],
                                alignment: 'center',
                                bold: true,
                                style: 'header',
                                text: 'All Search Results'
                              }
                            );
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text:      'Do Stuff',
                        action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                            alert( 'Button to DO Stuff activated' );
                             if (confirm('Are you sure you want to "Do Stuff"?') == true) {
$.ajax({
                                                  method: "POST",
                                                  url: "...",
                                                  contentType: 'application/json',
                                                  data: {items: stuffToDo, year:$('#year').val()},
                                                  success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
```

> Blockquote

Inside success (here), insert/modify code (or buttons.text above?) to update other button names after (this) button was pressed and all buttons were previously already initialized
??($('#searchDatatableResultsTable').dataTable()).button('pdfBtn:name' )???

Comment: It is straight forward. `$('.buttons-pdf').text('new caption')` etc ...You can do that in for example the `button-action.dt` event.

Comment: I accept your answer (although [I'm new and] I don't see a checkmark) since I got completely derailed by looking at only datatable solutions.  Albeit, the derived $('.buttons-pdf span.ui-button-text').text('new caption s') actually worked for me since the whole button was being replaced with the verbatim solution.   Thanks @davidkonrad